# Getting IllegalArgumentException: Cannot have both DTEND and DURATION in an event with updating a recurring all day event

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I'm updating an event in the calendar, using the CalendarProvider API as per the Android developer guidelines [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html).

I can create new recurring events, all day events, and recurring all day events without issues.

For some reason, if I try to update an existing recurring all day event, I get an exception.

The `ContentValues` object to the update looks like:

```
duration=PT1H dtstart=1371214800000 rrule=FREQ=WEEKLY
```

There's no `dtend` in there, just a duration.
Not sure why I'm getting the `DTEND` exception.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code here?

Answer (score 2):

Try to explicitly set the DTEND to null on the ContentValues.

Comment: This is actually working. 

cv.remove(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND) does not work for me
but
cv.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, (Integer) null) helped